# Difference between a state array initialized using literals and another state array initialized using the "new" operator in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Considering the contract below, what is the difference between:
a) arr_1 and arr_2
b) arr_3 and arr_4

```
contract Dummy{
    uint8[] public arr_1 = new uint8[](4);
    uint8[] public arr_2 = [0,0,0,0];
 
    function f() public pure {
        uint[3] memory arr_3;
        uint[] memory arr_4 = new uint[](3);
    }
}
```

Also, Solidity says that we can create local memory dynamic arrays using the new operator, like below:

```
 function f() public pure {
        uint[] memory arr = new uint[](3);
        //The following lines give error        
        //arr.push(10); //ERROR: local memory arrays dont support PUSH
        //arr.pop(); //ERROR: local memory arrays dont support POP
}
```

However, they don't support push and pop. So, how exactly are they dynamic?

The Solidity version I am referring to is ***0.8.13***

***EDIT*** Adding one more example, this time with gas costs

```
//Deplyment Cost: 171321
contract CostTest_0 {
    uint8[] public arr_0 = [0,0,0];
    
}

//Deplyment Cost: 172504
contract CostTest_1 {
    uint8[] public arr_1 = new uint8[](3);  //This is another way.   
}

//Deplyment Cost: 417617
contract CostTest_2 {
    uint8[] public arr_0 = [0,0,0];     //One way of declaring dynamic arrays
    uint8[] public arr_1 = new uint8[](3);  //This is another way.
    
    //31443
    function f() public {
        arr_0.push(100);
    }

    //31553    
    function g() public {
        arr_1.push(100);
    }
    //h(0) => 26188, h(1) => 26250
    function h(uint256 idx) public view returns (uint8) {
        return arr_0[idx];
    }
    //i(0) => 26144, i(1) => 26206
    function i(uint256 idx) public view returns (uint8) {
        return arr_1[idx];
    }


    //p(0) => 22030 , p(1) => 22042
    function p(uint256 idx) public pure returns (uint8) {
        uint8[] memory tmp = new uint8[](3);
        return tmp[idx];
    }
    //q(0) => 22009 , q(1) => 22021
    function q(uint256 idx) public pure returns (uint8) {
        uint8[3] memory tmp = [0, 0, 0];  
        return tmp[idx];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding differences between `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` and `arr4`;

`arr1` and `arr2` are state variables that are kept in storage, which means, they will exists even though transaction is finished executing

However, `arr3` and `arr4` are local memory arrays, that are cleared after execution.

There are **huge** gas differences between (1,2) and (3,4). Storage is much more expensive to use.

Any operation with a memory array will use 3 gas, (`mstore` and `mload`), While loading from storage uses `200` and writing to it uses at least `5000` (`sload` and `sstore`)

`arr2` will use slightly less gas to **deploy** compared to `arr1` since you are saving some computations and therefore a smaller bytecode. While using them, there should be no difference. This applies to `arr3` and `arr4` as well.

Using the variation with the `new` keyword, solidity allows you to decide the size in runtime, and this support comes naturally with some more gas costs given more computations. For example,

```
contract A {
    uint256 arrSize;
    constructor(uint256 _size){
        arrSize = _size;
    }

    function giveMeAnArray() public pure returns (uint256[]){
        uint256[arrSize] memory arr; // this is not allowed
        uint256[] memory arr = new uint256[](arrSize); // but this is allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts in helping me figure this out. My understanding of the subject is definitely better than it was before I asked the question.
In my opinion too, arr_1 should be slightly cheaper than arr_2 (and arr_4 cheaper than arr_3) becuase using the new operator , we ar e saving the gas costs of setting the values of the individual array items.
However, it seems that is not the case.
I have edited the  question to reflect the gas costs for different operations

Answer (score 1):

> Also, Solidity says that we can create local memory dynamic arrays using the new operator, like below:

1. Solidity doesn't support dynamic arrays in memory, it is only allowed in storage
2. The array in your code sample is not a dynamic array. You are creating a memory with a preallocated memory / array length.

So long story short:

No push/pop because they aren't really dynamic arrays in common sense

So I guess solidity documentation might be a little confusing regarding this. Imagine 3 different scenerios

- A static array, that you specify the length compile time. You can not resize it afterwards, and you need to know its size.

```
    uint[] memory arr = new uint[](4);
```

- The so called -static array with dynamic size-. You don't have to know it's exact size compile time, which means you can allocate the memory for array *dynamically*? in runtime. But this will still be a regular array, that takes `n consecutive memory slots` in the memory. So no `pop` or `push` methods that resize the array

```
    uint[] memory arr = new uint[](maxNumberOfTokens);
```

- A really dynamic array. For solidity, it is only possible in **storage**. You can resize it anyway you want. To see how solidity achieves dynamic arrays, you can take a look at [Layout in storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/internals/layout_in_storage.html), But in short; you take the keccak256 hash of the array's first slot that keeps it's length, and the array starts from the slot that corresponds to it's hash. So that we won't experience collisions

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays says "Memory arrays with dynamic length can be created using the new operator"

Comment: Thanks @keser . That makes sense. This means Solidity docs are apparently ambiguous, in that by "dynamic" the docs mean that the size of the memory arrays could be specified dynamically (eg. passed as an argument to the function); it did not mean the array was dynamic. Thanks for helping in understanding this better.

Could you please also comment on the first part of my question regarding the difference between arr_1 and arr_2 (and arr_3 and arr_4). I like to believe that apparently the difference is just syntactical sugar, but there seems to be a difference in gas costs, albeit very small

Comment: Hey @shariqkhan please accept one of the answers if it was helpful